# How to launch console application from terminal in Linux?

Tags: linux, console-application

I am using ubuntu distro,for your information. I have a console application (doesn't get any parameter, I just need to launch it.) How can I launch it from terminal?

And second question is that since console applications in Linux does not have a "window" can I see console ouputs on terminal?

I know this is a very basic question, but believe me I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: @eosterberg shouldn't I go to the directory or something?

Comment: and you should be in the same directory with your application to run ./yourApplication command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terminal:

> cd to the application directory

then type

> ./appname

You can see the output.

Comment: It says "command not found". should I enter an extention such as ".exe" ?

Comment: Okay working. Thank you. I was not typing "./" I will excetp the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: **Note:** to background the process, so your terminal doesn't sit there hung until you exit the console append and ampersand `&` to the end of the command. (e.g. `./yourapp &`) (you then type `fg` to bring it to the foreground)